# adding up data in a column

Tags: php, sql

I have a field `caloriesBurned` that should keep track of the total work out hours. I want to enter daily values into this field and have the field keep adding up the hours entered i.e monday 2 hrs wed 2 hrs ..`caloriesBurned` should be populated with 4 hrs....Is this possible? Here is my code.

```
$monthSum= mysql_query("SELECT caloriesBurned FROM workout WHERE userid = $userid");

$sql = mysql_query  ("UPDATE workout SET caloriesBurned = SUM($monthSum($caloriesToday)) WHERE userid = $userid");
```

Comment: Why do you want to keep an aggregated value in data table? If this is for some reporting purpose, keeping only CaloriesToday in the data table would be fine, and then SELECT query with GROUP BY can used for report generation.

Comment: The logic here doesn't seem to make sense. If it did, however, I'd advise you that there doesn't seem to be much point to bringing the data over into your PHP script, just write a query that sums the data and updates the table.

Comment: I want to be able to display to the user how many total hours for past 30 day .etc...

Comment: Also, please do not ever use the PHP "mysql" library. Use either PDO or mysqli. And preferably use only parameterized queries, never splice values into your SQL query strings.

Comment: You can get the total calories burned like this: `select sum(caloriesBurned) from workout where userid = $userid and workout_date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 30 days`

Comment: hmmm but it seems when someone enters their hours in for the day it changes the value to that days value in caloriesBurned... wont that  query just display that days input?